# How can I pass option has on rails hidden fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails and hidden_field_tag, I am reading on documentation

```
hidden_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})
```

So if I want to pass some option can I do

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :name, someOption: "option">
```

Is this right ? 
Can ruby handle that and recognize that the someOption: "option" is the third parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass only two parameters - you need to pass the 2nd parameter for value.

```
hidden_field_tag("name", "1", :id => "model_id") 
#set name to "name" 
#set value to "1" 
#set id to "model_id"
```

source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to give a value just pass nil for it but you have to pass the second argument. Otherwise Ruby would think that `someOption: "option"` is the second parameter and assign it to the value parameter.

```
 <%= hidden_field_tag :name, nil, someOption: "option">
```